# UITextView ContentSize.Height too high on iOS 6

Tags: ios, ios6, uitextview

I have the following code to calculate the height of a UITableView cell.

```
  UIFont *textFont = [SettingsManagerUI defaultFontItalicWithSize:14];

  UIView *tempView = [[UIView alloc] init];

  UITextView *locationText = [[UITextView alloc] init];
  UITextView *moreInfoText = [[UITextView alloc] init];

  [tempView addSubview:locationText];
  [tempView addSubview:moreInfoText];

  [locationText setFont:textFont];
  [moreInfoText setFont:textFont];

  NSString *locationDetails = [MembersSavePartnerDetailsMoreInfoTableCell generateLocationTextWithPartner:partner inLocation:location];
  locationText.text = locationDetails;

  NSString *moreInfo = partner ? partner.partnerDescription : location.partner.partnerDescription;
  moreInfoText.text = moreInfo;

  float locationTextHeight = locationText.contentSize.height;
  float moreInfoTextHeight = moreInfoText.contentSize.height;
```

In iOS 5.1.1, the `locationTextHeight` is 88 and the `moreInfoTextHeight` = 52.  In iOS 6, the heights are 1420 and 2482 respectively.

Why are the heights different in iOS 6 and how can I fix the issue?

Comment: I think I just realised what the issue is - I need to initialise the UITextView objects with a frame so that it knows what width to use for the Content size.  I'll be trying it soon and will post it as an answer if it proves to be the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by not initializing the UITextView with a frame.

```
UITextView *locationText = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGFrameMake(0,0,200,20)];
UITextView *moreInfoText = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGFrameMake(0,0,200,20)];
```

Before iOS 6, the UITextView must have had a default frame with a width greater than 0.